# IBM MFP 8.0 iOS crash when registerDevice for Push Notification

Tags: ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

After calling the `MFPPush.registerDevice` function, MobileFirst Platform plugin will obtain access token for scope `push.mobileclient`.
However, after received the access token response, the app crashes. Refer to attached image.

Any idea why this happening?

The MobileFirst Platform server and plugin version using : 
MobileFirst Platform 8.0.0.0 IF20170220 
cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2017021815 
cordova-plugin-mfp-push 8.0.2017012410

[image]

Comment: Can you please confirm if the issue happens only when using push? ie, if you were to connect to the MFP server ( without push plugin) do you see this issue?

Comment: @VivinK yes, if I take away the `MFPPush.registerDevice`, the app can use normally without any problem.

Comment: @YUN Is your `push.mobileclient` scope is protected with any security check ??

Comment: @VittalPai No, only added in scope-element mapping without any security check.

Answer (score 0):

@YUN the MFPPush.registerDevice function is working fine,
The MobileFirst Platform server and plugin version used :

MobileFirst Platform 8.0.0.00-20170325
cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2017021815
cordova-plugin-mfp-push 8.0.2017012410

hope it solves the issue.

Comment: The latest version of MobileFirst Platform 8.0 I found in official website is IF20170220-1900, I can't find 20170325.